# Send verification email after sign-up android app

Tags: java, android, verification

I'm building an Android app on Debian Jessie using Android Studio. I want to be able to implement an email verification system, where when the users sign up, they will automatically receive an email that will contain a link. Clicking on the link will change a value on the database from false to true so that the users are authenticated.

I have heard that I can use JavaMail API to accomplish this? But at the same time heard that I need to have an email server running on local host to send emails?

I still haven't found a definitive answer. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use parse.com as your database, it can take care of all of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

May be I don't know the best answer to this. There are two ways one can do this.

1. Send verification mail using the Web Services. i.e. Suppose you are using PHP web services to register user. When the user details is successfully stored in the database... you can generate a random code.... send mail to registered email address ... get that code in the response... and store it in preferences to check for validity.. when user enters it.
2. When the registration is successful.... you can send verification code to user by triggering some dialog or any other way... This is my code. I am using volley for network call.

   public class DialogRequestPassword extends Dialog implements
           android.view.View.OnClickListener {

   ```
   public Activity c;
   private PreferencesManager preferencesManager;
   DatabaseHelper db;
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   EditText request_password;

   public DialogRequestPassword(Activity a) {
       super(a);
       this.c = a;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       setContentView(R.layout.dialog_request_password);
       setCancelable(false);

       preferencesManager = new PreferencesManager(c);
       db = new DatabaseHelper(c);

       progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
       progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
       progressDialog.setMessage("Getting Information...");

       TextView connectButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
       connectButton.setOnClickListener(this);

       request_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.request_password);

       TextView dialog_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
       dialog_text.setText("Enter your registered email and request the lost password. You will receive steps to recover your password.");

       TextView cancelButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
       cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.cancelButton:
               dismiss();
               break;

           case R.id.connectButton:
               dismiss();
               // Send mail
               if (request_password.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                   request_password.setError("Enter registered Email");
               } else {
                   //Redirect user to Login
                   if (preferencesManager.getVerificationCode() == null) {
                       getUserData();
                   }
               }
               break;

       }
   }


   /*******************************/
   private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           progressDialog.show();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
           super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
           progressDialog.dismiss();
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(String... receipt) {
           try {
               GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("ro-reply@gmail.com", "password");
               sender.sendMail("Password Recovery for App title",
                       receipt[1],
                       "user@gmail.com",
                       receipt[0]);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.d("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
           }
           return null;
       }
   }


   private void getUserData() {
       StringRequest jsonAuthenticate = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.URL_REQUEST_PASSWORD,
               new Response.Listener<String>() {

                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(String response) {
                       if (Constants.DEBUG_MODE_ON)
                           Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_LOG, "Response for Request Paswword: " + response);

                       try {
                           JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
                           JSONArray jcode = result.getJSONArray("code");
                           JSONObject jCodeObj = jcode.getJSONObject(0);
                           int code = jCodeObj.getInt("code");

                           if (code == 1) {


                           } else {
                               progressDialog.dismiss();
                               Toast.makeText(c, "No such email is registered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }

                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           progressDialog.dismiss();

                           Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_LOG, "Volley Exception: " + e.getCause() + " -> " + e.toString());

                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Toast.makeText(c, "Oh! Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               progressDialog.dismiss();
               Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_LOG, "Error Response : " + error.toString() + " MESSAGE: " + error.getMessage() + " CAUSE:" + error.getCause());

           }
       }) {
           @Override
           protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
               Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

               params.put("email", request_password.getText().toString());
               return params;
           }
       };


       jsonAuthenticate.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
           @Override
           public int getCurrentTimeout() {
               return 10000;
           }

           @Override
           public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
               return 2;
           }

           @Override
           public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

           }
       });

       MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jsonAuthenticate);
   }
   ```

   }

Note : You will have to use GmaiLSender for this...

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Properties;

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;

static {
Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
}

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
this.user = user;
this.password = password;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
try{
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setDataHandler(handler);
if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
else
message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
Transport.send(message);
}catch(Exception e){

}
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
private byte[] data;
private String type;

public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
super();
this.data = data;
this.type = type;
}

public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
super();
this.data = data;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public String getContentType() {
if (type == null)
return "application/octet-stream";
else
return type;
}

public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
}

public String getName() {
return "ByteArrayDataSource";
}

public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
throw new IOException("Not Supported");
}
}
}
```